# non-abstract method calling abstract method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, abstraction

I am doubtful if a non-abstract method in abstract class can call abstract method internally ?

For Eg:

```
abstract class Car {
    abstract void startEngine();

    abstract void startRadiator();

    void start(String type) {
     if (type.equals("Engine")) {
          startEngine();
     else {
          startRadiator();
     }

}


class Maruti extends Car {
    void startEngine(){
        System.out.println("Starting the engine::");
    }

    void startRadiator(){
        System.out.println("Starting the Radiator::");
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Car c = new Maruti();
        c.start("Engine");
    }
}
```

Is this allowed? The answer is derived correctly, but want to understand if this is right design and we don't end up in any design problems in future?

Comment: Yes, it's allowed. The class will only be instantiated if based on a concrete child class of the abstract parent, and so the abstract method is guaranteed to be non-abstract when called.

Comment: But, It looks like the child class method is called from parent class?  Isnt it?

Comment: Far from being expressly prohibited, it is a known design pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: This pattern explanation helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's an accepted design and you will not have any issues/problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to call an abstract method from a non-abstract method. You have just to pay attention to not call start() inside a method called by start.
Also, i see your car type is defined as a string; why not using an Enumeration instated?

Comment: Enums cause backward compatibility when integrated with other parties. That's the reason i chose not to use enums and just keep it as string.